# How do you set functions for a button, on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

my function wont carry out for the button assigned. Im using visual studio code. For the
def myClick():
myLabel =Label(window, text ..., command...

it wont occur. on visual studio code, the 'myLabel' greys out and has the error 'is not accessedPylance'

```
# add response to input


def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Hello" + e.get() + "...      ")
myLabel.pack

# create button
myButton = Button(window, text="next", command=myClick, fg="black")
myButton.pack()
```

Comment: How do you know `"it wont occur."`?

Comment: it wont run, when i run the programe. the button doesnt do anything :/

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: when i click the button, nothing happens

Comment: And is that your real code? The line `myLabel.pack` doesn't seem right.

Comment: oh right its ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its just that you are not calling `pack()`. When I fix that I see the label appear:

```py
def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Hello" + e.get() + "...      ")
    myLabel.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pack myLabel inside the function, and add "()" at the end:

```
def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Hello" + e.get() + "...      ")
    myLabel.pack()

# create button
myButton = Button(window, text="next", command=myClick, fg="black")
myButton.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.
Firstly, `myLabel.pack()` is not aligned as `myLabel`.
You have to call the `pack()` method in the `myClick()` function.

Secondly, dont forget to use the brackets for calling the pack() method on myLabel.

You can see a working example down here.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Hello")
    myLabel.pack() # put this into the same level as myLabel

# create button
myButton = Button(window, text="next", command=myClick, fg="black")
myButton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the pack function. You wrote `myLabel.pack` without the brackets - `()` - so Python does **not** recognize it as a function.

Your code, improved:

```py
# add response to input


def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Hello" + e.get() + "...      ")
    myLabel.pack()

# create button
myButton = Button(window, text="next", command=myClick, fg="black")
myButton.pack()
```

Thanks for asking, keep up great work!